# Table Hint using WITH

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY CurveId, DeliveryDate, PeriodNumber 
                       ORDER BY publishdate ASC) AS [DuckCount]
FROM  
    mc.CURVEID_7017 
WHERE 
    CURVEID = 9152 
    AND DATEDIFF(hour,PublishDate, DeliveryDate) <= 24
OPTION (TABLE HINT(mc.CURVEID_7017, INDEX(IDX_CURVEID_7017)))
```

This works fine. Now I want to use it with a `WITH` keyword, but cannot get SQL Server to allow the table hint. It appears to not be valid within the `WITH (...)` section. If I move it outside, then it fails reporting that the table I'm hinting for is not part of the query. If anyone can show me how to perform the query below with the table hint I would be very grateful!

```
WITH filteredNew AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY CurveId, DeliveryDate, PeriodNumber 
                           ORDER BY publishdate ASC) AS [DuckCount]
    FROM  
        mc.CURVEID_7017 
    WHERE 
        CURVEID = 9152 
        AND DATEDIFF(hour,PublishDate, DeliveryDate) <= 24
    /*OPTION (TABLE HINT(mc.CURVEID_7017, INDEX(IDX_CURVEID_7017)))*/
)
SELECT
    DeliveryDate, value 
FROM 
    filteredNew
WHERE
    [DuckCount] = 1 
    AND DeliveryDate BETWEEN '1-sep-2015' AND '10-Nov-2015 23:59:59'
ORDER BY
    DeliveryDate ASC
```

The `HINT` makes a large performance difference. Any help appreciated!

Details: SQL Server 2008 R2

Please comment if I can provide any further detail.

Comment: Maybe you should look into updating the statistics or look at the data distribution before forcing indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Move the hint to the end. See [`OPTION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190322.aspx):

> Only one OPTION clause can be specified with the statement.

The *statement* is the entire `SELECT` query together with any preceding CTEs - the entire statement is compiled and optimized as a whole.

```
WITH filteredNew AS (
SELECT *, row_number() 
OVER (PARTITION BY CurveId, DeliveryDate, PeriodNumber ORDER BY publishdate ASC) AS [DuckCount]
FROM  mc.CURVEID_7017 WHERE CURVEID = 9152 AND DATEDIFF(hour,PublishDate, DeliveryDate)<= 24)
select DeliveryDate, value from filteredNew
where [DuckCount] = 1 AND DeliveryDate BETWEEN '1-sep-2015' AND '10-Nov-2015 23:59:59'
order by DeliveryDate asc
OPTION (TABLE HINT(mc.CURVEID_7017, INDEX(IDX_CURVEID_7017)))
```

Comment: thanks for reply.  However, the query above produces:
Msg 8723, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot execute query. Object 'mc.CURVEID_7017' is specified in the TABLE HINT clause, but is not used in the query or does not match the alias specified in the query. Table references in the TABLE HINT clause must match the WITH clause.

Comment: I have found that this stops ther error (using the alias):  OPTION (TABLE HINT(filteredNew, INDEX(IDX_CURVEID_7017)))